# Perl : can't install dependency using cpan

Tags: perl, cpanm

I have a scsript that uses package LWP::Curl
But when I try to install it using this command [sudo cpanm install LWP::Curl] get the following error :-

```
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SY/SYP/Net-Curl-0.37.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Net-Curl-0.37.tar.gz
Entering Net-Curl-0.37
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker::Config 0 ... Yes (6.66)
Configuring Net-Curl-0.37
Running Makefile.PL
pkgconfig failed:
Can't locate ExtUtils/PkgConfig.pm in @INC (you may need to install the ExtUtils::PkgConfig module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at Makefile.PL line 39.

Using curl-config script.
Can't exec "curl-config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 212.
curl-config failed:
Execution curl-config --vernum failed.
is your libcurl installed correctly ?


libcurl development files do not seem to be available
You must install libcurl 7.15.5 or newer to
build this module

NA: Unable to build distribution on this platform.
-> N/A
-> FAIL Configure failed for Net-Curl-0.37. See /home/harsh/.cpanm/work/1460968559.18563/build.log for details.
```

I am new to Perl , How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like  a bug in the Net::CURL package and it fails to list its dependencies correctly.

Install ExtUtils::PkgConfig first (just like the error message says).

Then install libcurl (the -dev version if your platform distinguishes between that and the base package) using your platform's package management system (again, like the error message says).